# How to create an elevator program in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create an elevator program where 2 values(1-10 floors) are given elevator current floor and floor which we want to go.

If the current floor = 1 and the floor to go = 9 it should alert from 2 to 9 and print Floor 9 reached also a prompt box that ask for new input on reaching each floor.

If a new floor entered is 4 and 5, it should print print Floor 4 reached print Floor 5 reached, when alert message prints 4 and 5 respectively.

```js
function lift() {
  var a = document.getElementById("fin").value // which floor to serve
  var b = document.getElementById("idle").value // lift currentposition
  var c = document.getElementById("ld").value // no of person
  var mxload = 11;
  if (c >= mxload) {
    alert("Max Load");
  } else {
    if (a > b) {
      alert("GOING UP")
      var x = parseInt(b) + 1;
      console.log(x)
      for (let i = x; i <= a; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          alert(i);
          var level = prompt("Enter the level - Current Level " + i, "");
          if (level > i) {
            console.log(level);
            document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "Reached Level" + " " + level + " " + "Doors Opened";
            for (let j = a; j <= level; j++) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                alert(j);
                document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "Reached Level" + " " + level + " " + "Doors Opened";
              }, 100);
            }

          }
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Reached Level" + " " + a + " " + "Doors Opened";
        }, 100);
      }
    } else if (a < b) {
      alert("GOING DOWN")
      var x = parseInt(b) - 1;
      for (let i = x; i >= a; i--) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          alert(i);
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Reached Level" + " " + a + " " + "Doors Opened";
        }, 100);

      }
    } else if (a == b) {
      alert("You are already in the same floor")
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  Enter the Floor No:<input type="number" id="fin" placeholder="1-9" /> Idle Floor<input type="number" id="idle" placeholder="1-9" /> Total Load<input type="number" id="ld" />
  <input type="button" id="sbt" value="Submit" onclick="lift()" />
  <p id="msg"></p>
  <p id="msg1"></p>
</body>
```

I can't enter more than 1 input in prompt field. It only works for 1 input in textbox and 1 input in prompt field.

Comment: You could use two prompts

Comment: for each level it should take value, if current is 1 floor to go is 10
it should alert from 1-6 with prompt box at 1,2,3....6. 
so if 7 ,8 ,9 is pressed at prompt boxes it should alert till 9 again with prompt boxes 
user can give any value from 1-10 depending on value it should alert

Comment: You may want to ask a more specific question, like "how to input multiple values with a prompt. Currently, it's a little hard to tell what you're asking.